# How to Initialize Generic Type in other class

Tags: .net, generics, asp.net-identity

Hi I am working on a generic solution where I am extending `System.Security.Principal.IIdentity` to add some more user Information. This component will be used in different solution again The user information will come from different sources like DB or Active Directory or even XML files. I have make some solution where an `IIdentityInitializer` will Initialize `IIdentity` and I will have different class implementing these interface.

```
public interface IIdentityInitializer<T>
where T:IIdentity
{
    T Initialize(string userid, string password)
}
public ActiveDirectoryIdentityInitializer<T> :IIdentityInitializer<T>
where T:IIdentity
{
    public T Initialize(string username, string password)
    {
        //Load Logic and assign data from Active directory to different property of T
    }
}

public DBIdentityInitializer<T>:IIdentityInitializer<T>
where T:IIdentity
{
    public T Initialize(string username, string password)
    {
        //Load Logic and assign data from DB to different property of T
    }
}

public CustomIdentity1:IIdentity
{
    public string Name{get;set}
    public string EMail{get;set;}
    public CustomIdentity1(IIdentityInitializer<CustomIdentity1> ci){}
}

public CustomIdentity2:IIdentity
{
    public string Name{get;set}
    public string EMail{get;set;}
    public string Mobile{get;set;}
    public string EmployeeId{get;set;}
    public CustomIdentity2(IIdentityInitializer<CustomIdentity2> ci){}
}
```

Now I have `ActiveDirectoryInitializer` and `DBInitializer` with `CustomIdentity1` and `CustomIdentity2` I have to know the Logic in Initialize that can work with in a generic way cause in future we can have more type of `IIdentity` and `IIdentityInitializer`.

Answer (score 0):

So this solution seems not quite right. Specifically, you're trying to make say a DBIdentityInitializer where yes, the database connection stuff is maybe generic but it also very much depends on the type T. That can't be made generic very easily. So it seems like it may be better to push as much of the work around accessing say, the database, into component that gets you an arbitrary entity from the data store - like an ORM. Then each DBIdentityInitializer now has a concrete type like DBCustomerIdentity1Initializer but the actual hard work comes in the ORM piece - the initializer is just a tiny little data-transformation class that represents the little hunk of unique logic to map one data type to another. So you still get type explosion, but more manageable. If you absolutely must push everything through one DBIdentityIntializer, I would recommend having the main class have a Dictionary> or some such that actually gets identity initializers registered with it: for example, an entry might actually be [CustomerIdentity1, DBCustomerIdentity1Initializer]. Alternatively, you might be able to use lambdas for the initializers instead of full-blown objects. At any rate, it's still the same solution, just with the composite parts all in one wrapper so one object can get passed around. Then T is used as a lookup and if an initializer exists, it initializes. Any time you use a dictionary with types though, you probably want to evaluate for a code smell.